# How to display the category name in the tab and post inside the tab in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, categories

I am using the [bootstrap nav tab](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/).
What I am doing is, I have a custom post type and I have created the custom category. I have 8 categories and each category has 10 posts.

I have to display the category name in the tab and post display inside the tab. I am getting the category name in the tab but not getting the post.

Below is the UI part

[image]

```
function dictionarytabview(){
global $post;
 $custom_terms = get_terms('dictionary_cats');
$data='<nav> <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">';
foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
$data.='<button class="nav-link" id="'.$custom_term->slug.'" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="'.$custom_term->slug.'" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="'.$custom_term->slug.'" aria-selected="true">'.$custom_term->name.'</button>';
}
$data.='</div></nav>';

  $args = array('post_type' => 'dictionary',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'dictionary_cats',
               // 'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
     $data.='<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">';
        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            $data.='<div class="tab-pane" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                          <div class="">
                          <h4>'.get_the_title().'</h4>
                          <p>'.get_the_content().'</p>
                          </div>
                  </div>';
        endwhile;
        $data.='</div>';

     }

wp_reset_query();
return $data;

}

add_shortcode( 'dictionary-tabview', 'dictionarytabview');
```

**Second way**

```
$data='';
$custom_terms = get_terms('dictionary_cats');
 $data='<nav> <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">';


foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    $data.='<button class="nav-link"  data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="'.$custom_term->slug.'" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="'.$custom_term->slug.'" aria-selected="true">'.$custom_term->name.'</button>';
}
 $data.='</div></nav>';
 $data.='<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">';
foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
   $args = array('post_type' => 'dictionary',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'dictionary_cats',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {            
        $data.='<div class="tab-pane fade" id="'.$custom_term->slug.'" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="'.$custom_term->slug.'">';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                 $data.='<div class="dic-post-list d-table w-100">
                 <div class="dic-inner-box headingBox"><h4>'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</h4></div>
                 <div class="dic-inner-box"> <p>'.get_the_content($post->ID).'</p></div>
                 </div>';
        endwhile;

                 $data.='</div>';

     }

}
           $data.='</div>';

        

        $data.='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
          jQuery(document).ready(function($){
             jQuery(".nav-tabs button.nav-link:first").addClass("active");
             jQuery(".tab-content .tab-pane:first").addClass("show active");

             $(".nav-tabs button").click(function () {
                $("button").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");   
                var tabactive=$(this).attr("data-bs-target");
                $(".tab-content .tab-pane").removeClass("show active");
                var a=$("#" + tabactive );
                a.addClass("show active");

            });
          }); 

</script>';
```

Comment: Your shortcode is `echo`'ing all the output, this means your shortcode will break lots of things, can't be nested and may not appear in the correct pace. Shortcodes ***must*** `return` their content as a HTML string. They cannot output directly under any circumstances. Also, your post loop has no `else` statement so if no posts were found it prints nothing and you would never know about it

Comment: @TomJNowell, Thanks for the valuable information. Let me update the code.

Comment: You can either use a variable to store the HTML then return it at the end, or capture the output using PHP output buffers then close the buffer and return its result at the end. I would also replace `wp_reset_query` with `wp_reset_postdata` and move it inside the `if` statement but after the loop. This does 2 things, `wp_reset_query` is meant to clean up after `query_posts` which you aren't using, and `wp_reset_postdata` cleans up after `the_post`. By moving it you avoid bugs when using the shortcode inside a nested `WP_Query` loop. I suspect the issue is your query found no posts

Comment: @TomJNowell, I have declared the $data variable and store the HTML code, and returning at the bottom.

Comment: @TomJNowell, I also tried the second way(code updated in the question) and I am getting my post but not in tabs.

Comment: Your code still has no `else { ... }` clause. I also see your indenting is broken, and that it hides several unrelated mistakes. It may be that even if your posts are being outputted, it wouldn't matter because your tabs depend on IDs that don't exist ( all your tab divs have the same ID. Can you confirm that if you hardcode your tabs to always have the same content instead of displaying posts that it still works? Have you checked the HTML source code looks good and that this is not a javascript or other issue? What does your browsers dev tool error console say?

Comment: Note that the `$data` variable isn't to fix the problem you asked about, it's to fix a more fundamental problem you didn't know you had. Shortcodes that use `echo` can break REST API endpoints, RSS feeds,  and cause lots of other problems such as broken page layouts. Right now because there is no `else` clause saying "no posts were found" we have no idea if it's the tabs that are broken, or if it's the query that's broken

Comment: I also see that you passed a taxonomy name to `get_terms`, but that is not how that function is supposed to work. Can you confirm to use that the tabs are showing and have the expected output?

Comment: @TomJNowell, Yes, I updated my second-way code in the question. Tabs are working. Now I am getting the same post in all the tabs. I have to show the category wise post

Comment: There's only a single post loop in your second code block for displaying posts, shouldn't there be a loop/query for each tab? It sounds like you have a button for every term but only a single tab in HTML, IMO this is a misunderstanding of how to implement a tabbed interface, querying for posts is not the issue

Comment: @TomJNowell, I implemented the second code and it's working with the tab. But I also got one issue and I am getting each post 5 times. I think something an issue with the foreach condition.

Comment: I found the solution. I comment out the foreach condition inside the while loop. I updated my second-way code. Can you please check it once... is it correct way?

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer rather than in your question? Fix the indenting as well as it makes the code difficult to read and hides bugs